# Disable 'Options' from the File Menu in Office 2007 applications

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, microsoft-office-2007, user-settings

We have deployed Office 2007 to multiple computers in an office environment (Windows Server 2008 and Windows XP CLients) and need to remove the 'Options' setting seen from the File menu.

Is there a way this can be achieved via group policy or similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no GPO setting to disable the Word Options button in the Office 2007 GPO templates. you need to create a custom Word document template with the options button disabled and then place it at one of the following locations (depending on Windows version):

C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP

If the computer is a terminal server or if it is otherwise used by multiple users you can also place the template at the following location:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\STARTUP

I have some lines of code that will show you how to do it, but I can't post them. If someone can tell me how to post them I'll gladly add them to this answer.

Comment: Thanks Joe for your response. I would be grateful if you can post your code. I think it is possible on here by, clicking on the binary icon in the editor for 'Your Answer'

Comment: I'll tell you what, it would be easier for me to make the actual templates available to you. You can download them from ftp.joewebster.com (using FTP of course). It should be obvious which is which when you download them. Put them in the paths described in my answer and that should do it for you.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I appreciate your help with this. Give my regards to Cleveland, I lived there for a couple of years in the late '90s, great place!

Comment: @heisenberg: Glad to help. Hopefully the templates work for you. BTW, love your uncertainty principal ;)

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks. If it is not too much bother can you tell me where in the template the options button is set to disabled.

Comment: I'll try to do that. I opened the template (somehow) and looked at the code but can't remember how I did it now. I might have used XML notepad, or something. If I get it open again I'll let you know the procedure.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to install the [Microsoft Office 2007 ADM templates](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=92D8519A-E143-4AEE-8F7A-E4BBAEBA13E7&displaylang=en).

Once you've done that, you will have control over Office 2007 via Group Policy.